# Why does backslash-escaping a CJK character cause a very-magic regex match to fail?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, unicode, encoding, multibyte

My understanding of [very-magic regexes](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) is that you can escape any character outside `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with a backslash to make it match literally.  However, I don't see that behaviour with CJK characters.  For example, compare:

```
:echo match('中','\v中')         " succeeds (returns 0)
:echo match('中','\v\中')        " fails (returns -1)
```

Why?

**Test environments**

`encoding=utf-8` in:

- official GVim 7.4 Win32 with `+iconv/dyn`, `+multi_byte_ime/dyn`, and `+multi_lang`.  (Strangely, it does not show `+multi_byte`, but UTF-8 editing works fine.)
- Vim 8.0 with `+iconv`, `+multi_byte`, and `+multi_lang` running in Cygwin through mintty 3.0.0.  `$LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `:h /\v`:

```
                            */\v* */\V*
Use of "\v" means that after it, all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z',
'A'-'Z' and '_' have special meaning: "very magic"
```

It's **ASCII** characters, not **any** characters.

According to `:h /\`:

```
                            */\* */\\*
\x  A backslash followed by a single character, with no special meaning,
    is reserved for future expansions
```

Therefore, `\中` has no meaning — it's just a reserved sequence.